# Simple User to User Rating function in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to add a field in my Django Project that will enable users to leave a review on another user's profile page. I understand that I need two ForeignKeys in my models.py, one for the user that will write the review and another for the user's profile where the review will be written on. I tried adding a `Profile FK` but I'm really not sure how to go about this or even what to include under the `Profile class`.

This is what I tried so far but I am getting an error that says:

> ValueError at /profile/7/ Cannot assign "<User: username>": "Review.profile" must be a "Profile" instance

I also need help with my views.py because as I play around the error message, I was able to finally post the review but it appears on the User's profile who wrote the review instead of the actual profile that I wanted to wrote it to. I am new to coding and tried really hard to read the django documentation about it but I can't really get past this one.

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, default='')
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="defaultDp.jpg")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    reviewmsg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reviewmsg)
```

views.py:

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
         rooms = user.room_set.all()
         reviews = user.review_set.all()
     
         if request.method == 'POST':
             review = Review.objects.create(
                 user=request.user,
                 profile=user,
                 reviewmsg=request.POST.get('reviewmsg')
             )
             return redirect('user-profile', pk=user.id)

         context = {'user':user, 'rooms':rooms, 'reviews':reviews}
         return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename your model fields it can make things a little clearer.  Here you are using 'user' to refer to both reviewer and reviewed.

I'd recommend something like the below, to make things clearer:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ...
```

Now you can more easily visualise what's happening

Another issue is your how you fetch the reviews and the fact you use

```
profile=user
```

...in your create function. However, Profile is a separate model, so you can't pass a user as an argument.

To make an assumption, generally users only need one profile, so want to have a one-to-one relationship between them. This is often expressed in the User model as your are unlikely to ever grab only the profile without the user.:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)


This leaves your profile for biographical info, phone numbers etc
    class Profile(models.Model):
         bio = models.TextField(...
         phone_num = models.CharField(...
```

If you did that, your view would look like this:

```
#renamed pk to user_id for clarity

def userProfile(request, user_id):
     user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
     rooms = user.room_set.all()
     #reviews = user.review_set.all()
     #this is where another problem lies. the only reverse foreign key 
     #from user to a User field in a Review model is to author! 
     #so you are getting all the reviews the user is the author of!
     #instead, try
     reviews = Review.objects.filter(profile__user = user)
 
     if request.method == 'POST':
         review = Review.objects.create(
             author=request.user,
             profile=user.profile,
             reviewmsg=request.POST.get('reviewmsg')
         )
         return redirect('user-profile', user_id=user_id)

     context = {'user':user, 'rooms':rooms, 'reviews':reviews}
     return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you @SamSparx! I followed your suggestion and made my models.py exactly as you said.  

`
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    reviewmsg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reviewmsg)
`

Comment: Hey @SamSparx! Thank you so much for your time, you've no idea how much I appreciate it. I copied the exact codes you suggested in models.py but I am now getting an error "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__pages_user.profile_id"
After looking it up, I run python manage.py migrate --fake and it finally went through. But another error is showing up on my project that says: "no such column: pages_user.profile_id".

I'm really sorry to drag you into this, I just can't afford to spend enough time to study about this because I'm working on a deadline. Thanks again!

Comment: Migrate fake stops the migration from actually being inacted. You'll need to solve the underlying problem. That error indicates you have two or more users with the same profile. The blunt force solution is to delete the database and migrations and start from scratch.  If that's impossible you might try going into /admin and changing any profiles that share users with other profiles. Finally you might try removing the user field from profile model in one migration,  then adding the profile field to the user model in a second migration.  Good luck!